# typelevel scala: ensure single instance of case class per constructor argument by typing alone?

Tags: scala, dictionary, fold, shapeless, type-level-computation

Let's say I have a trait and case classes corresponding to an expression language for a dsl.

```
sealed trait Expr[T]

case class Ident[T]() extends Expr[T]

case class Operator1[T](e1: Expr[T], e2: Expr[T]) extends Expr[T]
...
...
```

And that I also have a case class used to assign an expression to an identifier:

```
sealed trait DefLike[T]

case class Def[T](id: Ident[T], e: Expr[T]) extends DefLike[T]

case class Free[T](id:Ident[T]) extends DefLike[T]
```

The DSL is for a declarative language in which all identifiers can be given at most one definition.

```
So this would be accepted:

for { 
x <- Ident[Int]
y <- Ident[Int]
y_e <- Mult(Const(3), x) } yield Free(x) :: Def(y, y_e) :: Nil
```

However this would be forbidden:

```
for { 
x <- Ident[Int]
y <- Ident[Int]
y_e <- Mult(Const(3), x) } yield Free(x) :: Free(y) :: Def(x, x) :: Def(y, y_e) :: Nil
```

I also need to make sure that the sequence of definition is topoligically ordered, all of this at compile-time.

I was thinking of using shapeless Nat to assign an extra and unique type parameter to each identifier using some sort of wrapper function:

```
trait Expr[T] { type N <: Nat }
class Ident[T, M <: Nat]() extends Expr[T, M <: Nat] { type N = M }
...
...

object Builder {
   var i: Int = 0 
   def ident[T] = {i++; new Ident[T,intToNat(i)]}
}

trait DefLike[T, N <: Nat]
case class Def[T, N <: Nat](id: Ident[T,N], e: Expr[T])(implicit ev: GreaterThan[N, e.N]) extends DefLike[T, N]
case class Free[T, N <: Nat](id: Ident[T,N]) extends DefLike[T, N]
```

And then use some sort of type-level hackery to make the following work:

- The Nat type N assigned to any expression is the Max of the Nat types of its subexpressions.
- unique Nat Types are assigned to identifiers (doing it with a wrapper as above)
- an implicity GreaterThan[N, e.N] holds for Def[T, N](id, e): the Nat type of the defining expression is less than that of the identifier being defined (ensures topological ordering of definitions)
- define a type level constraint using type-level fold or type-level map to ensure that no two DefLike[T, N <: Nat] have the same N in a list of DefLike

Does it seem to be a good case for Nat ? 
How can I approach the fold over a type level list of types to detect type doublons?
Thanks,

Comment: Sounds promising, but you need `ident` to be typed at compile time, no? This might be a case for a small macro as I can't think of any way to do that in raw shapeless. Alternately you could require parameters to be named by singleton types? Detecting repeated types in a list is easy, you define a high-priority implicit for two of the same types in a list that explodes (or conflicts), and a low-priority implicit for arbitrary lists, so that you only get a valid implicit for type-level lists that don't contain a repeat.

Comment: Hi lmm, you are right, I did not realize my intToNat(i) was not evaluated at compile time.

Could you provide an example of your alternative solution with singleton types? I'm not experienced enough with singleton types.
Thanks for your insight.

Comment: Only the example from the shapeless docs, I haven't done much with them. I was thinking you could do e.g. `x ← Ident[Int]('x.narrow); y ← Ident[Int]('y.narrow)` and the types are different; no way to avoid the repetition that I can think of though, so the macro solution might be better. Best of luck either way.